# FileUpload component breaks application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng

I am trying to use the FileUpload Module to upload images to my api.
I installed primeng using `npm install --save primeng`
All the styles are applied as necessary.

My app.module.ts file looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/fileupload';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/accordion';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AccordionModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts looks like this:

```
<p-accordion>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header I" [selected]="true">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header II">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
      architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
      voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi.</p>
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header III">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati
      cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
      Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus.</p>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php"></p-fileUpload>
```

For some reason whenever i add the FileUpload the entire page is completely empty. According to the Chrome Dev Tools, my components are there but they are rendered at 0x0. Not even the accordion shows up, without the FileUpload the accordion works as expected.

Primeng Version: 10.0.0
Angular CLI Version: 10.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by accident, I had to import the HttpClientModule in the root module.ts.
Sad this isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs.